# Testing try/catch in Jasmine is not working

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have this piece of code in AngularJS that I'm trying to test:

```
var _savePendingChanges = function() {
  try {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('externalSave');
  } catch (e) {
    // Sometimes, AngularJS throws a "Cannot read property $$nextSibling of
    // null" error. To get around this we must use $apply().
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('externalSave');
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the test I've wrote until now, and it's not working (it throw the error from the `errorMessage` and a Jasmine error: `Error: Expected function to throw an Error.`):

```
fit('should save pending changes', function() {
    var errorMessage = 'Cannot read property $$nextSibling of null'; 
    spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.throwError(errorMessage);
    expect(function() {
      RouterService.savePendingChanges();
    }).toThrowError(errorMessage);
  });
```

Can anyone give me a hand on this? Thanks!

Comment: In your AngularJS function you are catching the error - so Jasmine is not detecting any error thrown. So I think you can test the $apply is being ran but not for the error as its being swallowed by the catch.

Comment: I've tried it but it wasn't working. After a few tries, I found out that when AngularJS methods are spied to throw an error, for some reason, the tests fails too. So I use a console.log after the first call for $broadcast and spied it. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can check that broadcast is called twice:

```
fit('should save pending changes', function () {
    var errorMessage = 'Cannot read property $$nextSibling of null';
    var broadcastSpy = spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.throwError(errorMessage);

    RouterService.savePendingChanges();

    expect(broadcastSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
});
```